# Show or anime where the main character uses a red dragon card to transform in to a suit of armor

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

Do you know an anime where the main character uses a red dragon card to transform in to a suit of armor?  One of his companions uses a blue shark card and the other one uses a brown rhino card to transform into the armor. They use a device that transports them in the cocoon where they fight.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  Was it hand-drawn animation or computer-rendered?

Comment: like 2017 and it animated but when they transform it becomes 3d animation

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Probably *[Majin Bone](https://myanimelist.net/anime/21835/Majin_Bone)*, a 2014 anime based on a card game.

[image: Title image for Majin Bone]

> Majin, the creator of the Universe, has been resurrected in the present day. Shougo Ryuujin, an ordinary high school student who transforms into the Bone Fighter Dragonbone with the Bone Card in order to save Earth. Together, with the other White Bone warriors take a stand against the Dark Bone, a foe that has appeared from darkness to devastate Earth. However, "could the true enemy be ourselves?"

The [media entry on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majin_Bone) mentions protagonists with dragon, shark, and rhinoceros forms, and the first two, at least, can be seen in the official trailer.

### Trailer

Found with a search for `anime card transform dragon shark rhinocerous`